# get File from JAR

Tags: java, spring, resources, io

I'm using Spring's [Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) abstraction to work with resources (files) in the filesystem. One of the resources is a file inside a JAR file. According to the following code, it appears the reference is valid

```
ResourcePatternResolver resourceResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

// The path to the resource from the root of the JAR file
Resource fileInJar = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("/META-INF/foo/file.txt");

templateResource.exists(); // returns true
templateResource.isReadable();  // returns true
```

At this point, all is well, but then when I try to convert the `Resource` to a `File`

```
templateResource.getFile();
```

I get the exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/foo/file.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/D:/m2repo/uic-3.2.6-0.jar!/META-INF/foo/file.txt        
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:198)
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getFile(ClassPathResource.java:174)
```

What is the correct way to get a `File` reference to a `Resource` that exists inside a JAR file?

Answer (score 19):

> What is the correct way to get a File
>   reference to a Resource that exists
>   inside a JAR file?

The correct way is not doing that at all because it's impossible. A `File` represents an actual file on a file system, which a JAR entry is not, unless you have a special file system for that.

If you just need the data, use `getInputStream()`. If you have to satisfy an API that demands a `File` object, then I'm afraid the only thing you can do is to create a temp file and copy the data from the input stream to it.

Comment: @David Williams: simply call getInputStream() instead of getFile()

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read it, just call `resource.getInputStream()`

The exception message is pretty clear - the file does not reside on the file-system, so you can't have a `File` instance. Besides - what will do do with that `File`, apart from reading its content?

Comment: that will give me an InputStream, but what I really want is a File

Comment: what will you do with that `File`?

Comment: Pass it to an API that requires a File

Comment: well in that case create the `File` at a temporary location

Answer (score -1):

A quick look at the [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html#getFile%28%29) you provided for Resource documentation, says the following:

```
Throws: IOException if the resource cannot be resolved as absolute file path, 
i.e. if the resource is not available in a file system
```

Maybe the text file is inside a jar? In that case you will have to use `getInputStream()` to read its contents.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding an example to the answers here.  If you need a **`File`** (and not just the contents of it) from within your JAR, you need to create a temporary file from the resource first. (The below is written in Groovy):

```
    InputStream inputStream = resourceLoader.getResource('/META-INF/foo/file.txt').inputStream
    File tempFile = new File('file.txt')
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)

    try {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception
    } finally {
        outputStream.close()
    }
```